# Salesforce: Any Rest API available for accessing Salesforce Calendar?

Tags: salesforce

How to access the Salesforce Calendar information using
REST API.Calendar information means all the tasks, meetings and so on.
Is there any Rest API available particularly for accessing Salesforce Calendar using Javascript/Java...
 Thanks in Advance...

Comment: I am looking for documentation regarding the REST API & accessing Calendar information as well. I found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_event.htm); maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the REST API guide, which describes how you use the REST API: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/

And here is a link to the Salesforce Standard Objects and what you can do with each of them through the API:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_list.htm

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you have to first login:

- `POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/login_url` with:

  - `login_url` from Setup>Generate Enterprise WSDL>`Generate`, look for `<soap:address location=`
  - `security_token` from Profile>Settings>`Reset My Security Token`
  - Headers `Content-Type=text/xml` & `SOAPAction=""`

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:login>
      <urn:username>your_login</urn:username>
      <urn:password>concatenate_password_and_security_token</urn:password>
    </urn:login>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then you can make any SQL query, such as for the `Task` object:

- `POST https://serverrl` with:

  - `server_url` & `session_Token` from login xml response
  - Headers `Content-Type=text/xml` & `SOAPAction=""`

```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:SessionHeader>
         <urn:sessionId>session_Token</urn:sessionId>
      </urn:SessionHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:query>
        <urn:queryString>
            SELECT Subject, Type, Status, WhoId FROM Task WHERE WhoId != NULL
        </urn:queryString>
    </urn:query>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Sample Response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sf="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <LimitInfoHeader>
            <limitInfo>
                <current>123</current>
                <limit>1234</limit>
                <type>API REQUESTS</type>
            </limitInfo>
        </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <queryResponse>
            <result>
                <done>true</done>
                <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
                <records xsi:type="sf:Task">
                    <sf:Status>Completed</sf:Status>
                    <sf:Subject>Email: xxx    [ ref:xxx:ref ]</sf:Subject>
                    <sf:WhoId>0034Hxxx</sf:WhoId>
                </records>
                <records xsi:type="sf:Task">
                    <sf:Status>Not Started</sf:Status>
                    <sf:Subject>Email: xxx    [ ref:xxx:ref ]</sf:Subject>
                    <sf:WhoId>0034Ixxx</sf:WhoId>
                </records>
                <size>37</size>
            </result>
        </queryResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Source https://blog.floriancourgey.com/2020/10/salesforce-soap-api-external-call